# PHP die() from included page without dying from main page

Tags: php

Is there a way to use the `die()` function to stop executing PHP statements on a page included on another page, but continue the execution of PHP statements on the page on which the file containing the `die()` function was included?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `return;` in your included file. It will stop this include execution. It works like a function. Also you can return a value from your included file

Comment: thats the price for searching the correct cites and links to the PHP docs.. you were 3 minutes faster :-(

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, it looked cool to me too when I first time seen it. In my 5+ year experience I used this only one time and in one place of my framework's code

Comment: @Kaii, yeah I understand. +1 for given detailed answer

Answer (score 9):

No. [`die`](http://www.php.net/die) is an alias for [`exit`](http://www.php.net/exit) which immediately stops all script execution.

But you can use [`return`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) instead, which does exactly what you want:

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was `include()`ed or `require()`ed, then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the current script file was `include()`ed, then the value given to `return()` will be returned as the value of the `include()` call. If `return()` is called from within the main script file, then script execution ends.

As stated in the excerpt from the [PHP docs](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php), you can even use it to give a exit code / return value back from the include:

```
$include_retval = include('file_like_function.php');
if ($include_retval) {
    die("include returned error code: " . $include_retval);
}
```

Comment: awesome answer. wish I could +2 it.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could use `try` blocks instead?

```
  try
  {
    include $file;
  }

  catch (Exception $e)
  {
    // Whatever
  }
```

And throw an exception where you would use `die()` in `$file`.