# stop php execution instead of just a php script in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, exit, execution

I am using Codeigniter for a project and i usually call a series of models (let's say controllerA -> modelA -> modelB -> modelC) for some work. I want the php to stop executing when it reaches some exception where i invoke the `exit()` command. Now, if the command `exit()` is invoked in modelB, will it stop execution of only the script of modelB and continue executing rest of the modelA? Or will it stop the entire execution flow.

I really don't know how to put this question here. The question looks quite messy. Please let me know should i need to revise the question itself.

Comment: It should stop after modelB exit. But you can try exit in Model B and echo 'something' in modelC.

Comment: okay........ that's a great suggestion....... i will try that and post here.

Comment: right......... it stops at modelB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`exit`](http://www.php.net/exit) stops all script execution immediately, regardless where you call it.

The opposite is [`return`](http://www.php.net/return) which only stops execution of the current function (or current file when used at global level in an included file)

Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9853554/43959

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you call the exit() function, all code will stop executing. This includes the other files because codeigniter just 'requires' them.

Answer (score 2):

It stops the execution from that line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want, but maybe you can use exceptions to control PHP code execution.

http://es.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Like someone mentions above you should `return` from a function, or If your in a loop you could use `continue` or `break`